Unable to run script as scheduled task on startup
I have the following command which runs without a problem from either the Command prompt or from a *.bat file.
powercfg /change standby-timeout-ac 120

However, when I try to run it as a scheduled task, it does not execute, either when triggered by the trigger "System Start", or when trying to run manually.
Task fails with Error Code 2147943726.
This error code seems to have something to do with a bad password, but I have ensured the password is correct (and the user does have admin privileges)
I also found a recommendation to set "stop existing task if running" but this did not change anything.
Oh, and selecting the .bat file instead of the hard-coded script is equally ineffective in getting this task to run.
Here are the task settings (from the XML task export):

